# How can I provide an optional link to a Forum from a node (D7)?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have custom node types 'foo' or 'bar', and each node should have its own associated forum you can easily navigate to from that node. I was hoping to eventually use the rules module to generate the forum upon 'foo' or 'bar' creation.

To both 'foo' and 'bar' I've added a custom Term reference field which is validated against the Forum taxonomy, and I have **not** marked the custom field as required. But when trying to save any of these content types, it's making this forum reference required. Why?

Possibly related - when I add this custom field to a pre-existing content type and then view a node of that type, I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$forum_tid in forum_node_view() (line 271 of modules/forum/forum.module).

And if I try to edit, I get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: und in advanced_forum_type_is_in_forum() (line 1038 of sites/all/modules/advanced_forum/advanced_forum.module).
>   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in advanced_forum_type_is_in_forum() (line 1038 of sites/all/modules/advanced_forum/advanced_forum.module).

(Yes, I'm also using Advanced Forums, but I think this is more fundamentally a base Drupal 7 Forum module issue.)

[This topic](http://drupal.org/node/690328) (which is marked as a duplicate of [this](http://drupal.org/node/613272)) is as close as I could come to finding a similar error, but seems to imply that I'm trying to save a **forum node** (as opposed to 'foo' or 'bar') without linking it to a forum term (forum or container). Which makes some sense as when I *do* provide a valid value to the custom Term reference field, the 'foo' or 'bar node will show up as a thread in the associated forum and the breadcrumb on node 'foo' or 'bar' acts like a forum node breadcrumb. However, I really don't want my 'foo' node to act like a forum node.

So I'm guessing that trying to link to a forum from an arbitrary node using a Term reference custom field is a Bad Idea. How can I do this without hardcoding a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [entityreference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference). Create a rule that generates the forum on node creation and then an action that creates an entity reference in the original node.